# Perl fork() shared memory

Tags: perl, fork

Is there any way to load read-only variables into memory before forking and keep them there without using up virt memory x number of children?

It seems to be a common opinion that read-only memory is shared by default and is copied on write. I ran a test and found this to be untrue:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $data;
$$data = 'a'x 1_000_000; #keep it in a ref just in case that matters

foreach (0..10){
    last unless my $pid = fork();
}   
<STDIN>;
```

While the process is sitting on STDIN, I check top:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND   

15982 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15983 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15984 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15985 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15986 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15987 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15988 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15989 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15990 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15991 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t                             
15992 wdev      20   0  121m 2540  188 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 foo.t
```

Sure enough, practically all the memory is in individual child processes.

Is there something I am missing, or does forking a perl process really copy over the entire set of data structures for each child?

Comment: You are using the wrong test.  You need to use something that can actually tell the difference between shared and not-shared pages.  What that tool might be is OS-specific; on Linux, we use `Linux::Smaps`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either this is operating-system dependent or you're not seeing what you think you're seeing.  I modified your test script to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl    

print `free`;

my $data = [ ('a') x 1000000 ];

for (1 .. 10) {
  print `free`;
  last unless fork;
} 

sleep 10;
```

Running it with `./forktest | grep Mem`, I get output such as:

```
Mem:       3979908    2866552    1113356          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2917888    1062020          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2918284    1061624          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2918532    1061376          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2918936    1060972          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2919404    1060504          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2919900    1060008          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2919900    1060008          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2920148    1059760          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2920148    1059760          0     667388    1258560
Mem:       3979908    2920496    1059412          0     667388    1258560
```

in which the second column of numbers (third column overall) is the total system RAM usage.  Note that it increases from 2866552 to 2917888 when `$data` is assigned at the start of the program, then stays fairly steady from there on as the forks are done.

I suspect that what you're seeing in `top` is that it uses "shared memory" in the IPC-specific sense (i.e., chunks of memory which have been explicitly requested and allocated as "shared") and pages which are currently available to multiple processes on a copy-on-write basis do not meet that definition.

Comment: OK, you are correct. I have run several tests using free to demonstrate that data is indeed shared. What top shows still mystifies me.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

The [perl docs on fork](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/fork.html) say "File descriptors (and sometimes locks on those descriptors) are shared, while everything else is copied."

Actually it means that all (code and) data of the process is copied on fork, but file descriptors in the process' address space are basically references to shared kernel structures.
So the *same* file *can* be accessed by parent and children.

Comment: You missed the next sentence in the doc: "On most systems supporting fork(), great care has gone into making it extremely efficient (for example, using copy-on-write technology on data pages), making it the dominant paradigm for multitasking over the last few decades."